# GC taking more then 70% of total time

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have a code that dynamically creates instances of an unknown type using Expression-trees.

```
public IEnumerable<T> CreateMany<T>(int number, params object[] args)
{
    var activator = GetActivator<T>(args);

    List<T> result = new List<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) result.Add(activator.CreateInstance<T>(args));
    return result;
}
```

The `GetActivator`-method simply returns a delegate (`Activator`) to the constructor of type `T` that matches the given `args`.

Within that second class I have this code for the activator (the delegate):

```
public static class GenericTypeFactory
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Delegate to the constructor
    /// </summary>
    public delegate object Activator(params object[] args);

    public static T CreateInstance<T>(this Activator activator, params object[] args)
    {
        // call the delegate (that points to the constructor)
        return (T)activator(args);
    }
```

When running dotTrace multiple times I notice that when executing the `CreateMany`-method more then 70% of the time only GC is running (where I cannot further dig in with dotTrace). But I´m not sure WHERE all those references come from and WHY GC allways releases them at the same time (allways when running that particular method). Anyone has an idea why this may happen?

Comment: I doubt people will be able to help you without a working code sample that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Try using CLRProfiler to find out what kind of memory you're allocating. Also, careful with dotTrace - it tells you that 70% of the work done in `CreateMany` is the GC, but that doesn't always mean that `CreateMany` is also a *cause* of the GC. It might simply be that it's happening after some memory intensive operation that happened to release all its references just before a call to `CreateMany` (or `result.Add`). Another point is the `object[]` if you're using value-type arguments, and the use of `List` in the first place - why not initialize it with a given capacity when you know it?

Comment: The simple explanation is that *number* is large.  Inevitably triggering a collection because the number of objects you allocate cannot fit in gen #0.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: Try to profile your app by dotTrace in 'Timeline' mode, it will show you where memory traffic is produced, also it shows more accurate information about GC time.